# Разметка Notification для отображения загрузки

Tags: android

Приветствую!
У кого-нибудь есть разметка для Notification-а, та, которую использует маркет для отображения загрузки, либо стандартная разметка для уведомлений,чтобы её переделать?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну насчет именно маркета не знаю, но стандартные лэйауты для Notification есть.

Фтыкаем [сюда](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/status_bar.xml?av=f)

Comment: Спасибо, переделал этот вариант

Answer (score 2):

Вот [ТУТ](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140928/) по-русски и с комментариями, очень наглядно.

Comment: Спасибо, как я мог пропустить такую классную статейку!